# Get value from InterpolatingFunction

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, filtering

I'm trying to find `My[t]`, `Mx[t]` and `Mz[t]` values when evaluated at `t = Infinity`.

Code to date:

```
γ = 2.675*10^8;
T1 = 100*10^-3;
T2 = 10*10^-3;
B0 = 2;
M0 = 1*10^-1;
B1 = 1*10^-7;

(*Above are constants*)

NDSolve[{Mx'[t] == -Mx[t]/T2, Mx[0] == 0}, Mx, {t, 0, 0.5}]

NDSolve[{My'[t] == γ*Mz[t]*B1 - My[t]/T2,
  Mz'[t] == -γ*My[t]*B1 + (M0 - Mz[t])/T1,
  My[0] == 0, Mz[0] == M0}, {My, Mz}, {t, 0, 0.5}, 
 MaxSteps -> Infinity]

Plot[Evaluate[Mx[t] /. %], {t, 0, 0.5}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[t, 14], Style[Subscript[M, x], 12]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]

Plot[Evaluate[{Mz[t], My[t]} /. %], {t, 0, 0.5}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[t, 14], Style[M, 14]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(y\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(z\)]\)"}, {0.9, 0.85}], 
 ClippingStyle -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: The styling of your question can be improved. Please take the time to read the [markdown help page](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You'll better communicate your problem when you use the right formatting.

Comment: You know Gamma is a Function, see [Gamma](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gamma.html), and your [ ] are possibly ill placed.

Comment: If the code is evaluated in order you are using `%` incorrectly. (first usage tries to get `MX` from the `My,Mz` solution for example) I'd suggest actually assiging the `NDSolve` results to symbols and using those instead of relying on output history (`%`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

*george2079* pointed out that using approximate numbers created a problem with the solution for high values of `t`. Replacing the approximate value for `gamma` with a rational number, the problem is stable at high values, including infinity.

```
γ = 267500000;
t1 = 1/10;
t2 = 1/100;
b0 = 2;
m0 = 1/10;
b1 = 1/10000000;
```

`DSolve` works with your equations.

The first differential equation yields a constant value for `mx[t]` of zero so I will skip it.

The second differential equation gives:

```
solYZ = 
 DSolve[{my'[t] == γ*mz[t]*b1 - my[t]/t2, 
   mz'[t] == -γ*my[t]*b1 + (m0 - mz[t])/t1, my[0] == 0, 
   mz[0] == m0}, {my[t], mz[t]}, t]

(* {{my[t] -> (1/11501679980)
   107 E^(-55 t - (Sqrt[20951] t)/4 - 
     1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) (1676080 E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2) - 
      838040 E^(1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) - 
      18649 Sqrt[20951] E^(1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) - 
      838040 E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2 + 1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) + 
      18649 Sqrt[20951]
        E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2 + 1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t)), 
  mz[t] -> (1/11501679980)
   E^(-55 t - (Sqrt[20951] t)/4 - 
     1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) (670432000 E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2) + 
      239867999 E^(1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) - 
      2518780 Sqrt[20951] E^(1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) + 
      239867999 E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2 + 1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) + 
      2518780 Sqrt[20951]
        E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2 + 1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t))}} *)
```

We can create functions out of the solutions in a number of ways. Below is one method:

```
my[t_] = solYZ[[1, 1, 2]]

(* (1/11501679980)107 E^(-55 t - (Sqrt[20951] t)/4 - 
  1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) (1676080 E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2) - 
   838040 E^(1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) - 
   18649 Sqrt[20951] E^(1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) - 
   838040 E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2 + 1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) + 
   18649 Sqrt[20951]
     E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2 + 1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t)) *)
```

and for `mz[t]`

```
mz[t_] = solYZ[[1, 2, 2]]

(* (1/11501679980)E^(-55 t - (Sqrt[20951] t)/4 - 
  1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) (670432000 E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2) + 
   239867999 E^(1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) - 
   2518780 Sqrt[20951] E^(1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) + 
   239867999 E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2 + 1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t) + 
   2518780 Sqrt[20951]
     E^((Sqrt[20951] t)/2 + 1/4 (-220 + Sqrt[20951]) t)) *)
```

Now we can plot it:

```
Plot[{my[t], mz[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It appears to quickly approach a constant. If you take the limits you will find:

```
Limit[my[t], t -> ∞]
(* 428/27449 *)

Limit[mz[t], t -> ∞]
(* 1600/27449 *)
```

Comment: FWIW `NDSolve` does not diverge like that for large t. (perhaps a bifurcation?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a numerical precision issue with evaluation the analytic solution.  If you make all the parameters exact ( gamma=267500000) this goes away.

Comment: @george2079 You are correct. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but it's a start:

```
γ = 2.675*10^8; 
T1 = 100*10^-3; 
T2 = 10*10^-3; 
B0 = 2; 
M0 = 1*10^-1; 
B1 = 1*10^-7;

nds1 = NDSolve[{Mx'[t] == -Mx[t]/T2, Mx[0] == 0}, Mx, {t, 0, 0.5}]

nds2 = NDSolve[{My'[t] == γ*Mz[t]*B1 - My[t]/T2,
Mz'[t] == -γ*My[t]*B1 + (M0 - Mz[t])/T1, My[0] == 0, 
Mz[0] == M0}, {My, Mz}, {t, 0, 0.5}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]

Plot[Evaluate[Mx[t] /. nds1], {t, 0, 0.5}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style[t, 14], Style[Subscript[M, x], 12]}, 
PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]

Plot[Evaluate[{Mz[t], My[t]} /. nds2], {t, 0, 0.5}, 
PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotRange -> All, 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

> [image]

[image]

[image]